# Wordpress redirect, output headers already sent

Tags: redirect

I have a shortcode to display a form. When the user tries to click on the button to redirect to another page, I get `headers already sent` error. If I use javascript redirection, the redirection works.

But I would like to know what is wrong with the code that it is throwing this error:

Shortcode code:

```
/**
     * Processes shortcode 
     *
     *
     *
     * @return  mixed   $output     Output of the buffer
     */
    public function plugin_calc() {
        ob_start();

        include 'templates/get-form-calculator.php';
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;

    }
```

get-form-calculator.php:

```
$nameErr = $emailErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $valid = true;
 if (empty($_POST["cf-name"])) {
     $nameErr = "This field is required";
     $valid = false;
 } else {
     $name = strip_tags($_POST["cf-name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
         $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
         $valid = false;
     }
 }

 if (empty($_POST["cf-email"])) {
     $emailErr = "This field is required";
     $valid = false;
 } else {
     $email = strip_tags($_POST["cf-email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
         $valid = false;
     }
 }

 if ($valid) {
    if (isset($_POST['cf-request-quote'])){
         $cf_name = $name;
         $cf_email = $email;
         $url = home_url( '/rquote/?cfn=' . urlencode($cf_name) . '&cfe='. urlencode($cf_email));
         //wp_safe_redirect( $url );  //This doesn't work
         echo '<script> window.location = "'.$url.'"; </script>'; //This works
         exit();
     }
 }

}

?>

//HTML Form Code here
```